# How Can I Solve Java NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, api, token

i'm trying to get a developer access token response from a website but i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jboss.resteasy.util.CaseInsensitiveMap.putSingle(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
```

when i try to do what they said in their document.

my class file:

```
import org.apache.coyote.Request;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

@SpringBootApplication
public class IninaltestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IninaltestApplication.class, args);

        Request request= new Request();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.putSingle("Authorization",
                "Basic XXX");
        headers.putSingle("Date",new Date());
        headers.putSingle("Content-Type","application/json");
        headers.putSingle("Language","TR");
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("XXX");
        Response response =webTarget.request().headers(headers).post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
        String resStr = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(resStr);
```

The error comes from post() method and i don't know  how to solve this.

And i am sharing my pom.xml file with you here is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ininaltest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ininaltest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I couldn't find where the error comes from.

Comment: Post more (or all) lines of the stack trace. NoSuchMethodError occurs when this method really isn't in the class. Could be a lib mismatch. Post your build config (maven, gradle, ...).

Comment: I shared my pom.xml file

Comment: Looks like you are combining jars from different versions of rest easy. I see 3.0.2. 3.0.9 and 3.0.12 I would suspect those to be the same. The `maven-compiler-plugin` as a dependency doesn't make sense. I also don't really get what Spring (Boot) has to do with this as the code doesn't use that at all (there is something but doesn't do anything or is used).